# after migrating magento site to aws ec2 I got 'Undefined index' error

Tags: php, magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have migrated my magento site from shared hosting to aws ec2 ubuntu server. I have done database import successfully. But when I hit public IP of ec2 server. I got

> Undefined index: items  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 166
>
> Notice: Undefined index: items  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 166

please give suggestion to fix these issue

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, notices are errors for things you may have done wrong, or have the potential for causing bugs.

Its likely you previous environment had this error level disabled, which is why you didn't see it before.

You have two options:

1. Fix the cause of the error.
2. Disable notice level with the `error_reporting` directive in php.ini. (Make sure you restart your webserver/php after this change)